# How to track tree DOM changes without reloading the page? Angular

Tags: angular, dom, mutation-observers

I need your help. I have a small piece of code with which I am trying to implement the following logic - I have a menu list. If I have the `root` role, do not delete anything, but if the non-root role has changed, then delete the item of menu. Now my logic works, but only after reloading the page. Had the role of root, changed to another and the element is deleted only after reloading the page. `ChangeDetectorRef`, `MutationObserver` and `applicationRef.tick()` did not help me unfortunately. Please tell me how can I track it or do deletes and adds along with its result without rebooting? Thank you very much

```
@ViewChildren('menuItems') menuElements: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    let menuArrayElements = this.menuElements.toArray();
    let element = menuArrayElements.find((el) => el.nativeElement.innerText === 'Platform setup');
    if (this.role !== 'root') {
        element.nativeElement.parentNode.removeChild(element.nativeElement);
    }

    const observer = new MutationObserver(list => {
        console.log(list)
    })
    observer.observe(element.nativeElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });
}
```

Comment: How is the role changing - by actions inside the app, or by actions on the api/backend? In other words, how do you get user's role?

Comment: @MishaMashina The role is changed using the API. There are several roles to choose from and the menu should change. `this.store$.select(selectors.currentUserRole)
   .subscribe(role => )` - using ngrx and api i follow and change role

Comment: I wasn't clear, I guess. What I wanted to know is if you're changing the role through UI, or changing it manually (or through some service) in api. If you're changing it through UI, then you can make it a subject to subscribe to, but if you're changing it in api you won't be able to trigger the change on frontend through simple http subscription - you'd need a socket or something else that listens in realtime.

Comment: @MishaMashina I have several buttons for each role. And through the UI I change the user role. Let's continue this topic in the chat, because now there may be a warning not to discuss the topic in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Angular tools except for calling the DOM API. I mean you're not supposed to use `removeChild` directly in the Angular app. Instead, I suggest using the binding. For example, you could write in component:

```
private role$ = new BehaviorSubject('root');  // should be updated when the role changes

private menuItems$ = [{
   name: 'first link',
   href: '/first',
   rootOnly: false
}, {
   name: 'second link',
   href: '/second',
   rootOnly: true
}];

// an observable that removes menu item when the role changes
menuItemsProtected$ = combineLatest([this.role$, this.menuItems$]).pipe(
  map(([role, items]) => {
    if (role === 'root') {
      return items;
    }
    return items.filter((e) => !e.rootOnly);
  })
);
```

Then in your template:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of menuItemsProtected$ | async">
  <li>
    <a [routerLink]="item.href">
      {{item.name}}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now you just need to implement `role$` as a BehaviorSubject (for example), see more details here https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject